# Video tearing In Xubuntu

Tags: unity, xubuntu, video, xfce, tearing

I am using Xubuntu 17.04 with XFCE, Xubuntu and Ubuntu desktops (Enviroment). On play high fps videos on Xubuntu session I observe video tearing. Even when I scroll down in my browser video tears. I see no such problem in Ubuntu session, using the same applications.

I prefer to use Xubuntu as it is more lightweight, so how can I solve this problem in Xubuntu?

Comment: Try to enable compositing as described here: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7417

Comment: Thanks now I don't need to use Ubuntu session anymore.

Comment: @DDK You solved it. Please post your comment as an answer so I can upvote it.